# How can I boost my Key Performance Review?

Tags: performance-reviews

I am a software developer, working on a new country, first as a contractor and now in a permanent role. My Key Performance Review (KPR) is in  1.5 months, where my contract will be extended and possibly renegotiated.

What details, other than professional performance (my actual job tasks), should I take into account to make the best impression. How can I display to the directors and co-workers that I am an awesome team player?

Comment: These overly broad *"how can I be more awesome?"* questions are not going to be the best use of this site. Where are you lacking? How have you tried to improve in these area? What specific problems have you encountered? -- Those are the type of *specific* day-to-day questions that users have a chance of answering. This is entirely to generalized to be useful. Users will be left guessing what type of advice will actually help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at the review criteria, and take the time now (several weeks before the review) to schedule a meeting with your supervisor about what the criteria mean to them, and to get examples of behaviors that score highly.

The best source of information on how to increase your score will always be from the people providing the score. Taking the initiative to schedule a meeting yourself weeks (or better yet, months ahead of time) will not only look good, it will give you time to make changes based on the feedback you get in order to score better than you would have otherwise.

Basically, it never hurts to ask, and starting an open dialog is pretty much always a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these  two items may help you:

- you're a fast learner, willing to investigate more that the day to day issues (ie learning a new language);
- you are going to participate in/organize developer-focused meetings in order to find new ways to do your job;

Then ensure you will keep these promises :)